# Text overflow ellipsis does not work with header tags

Tags: html, css

Why the ellipsis does not show when a header tag is overflown? How can I show the ellipsis for header tags?

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h4>Ellipsis does not work with header tags</h4>
   <span>Ellipsis does work with span tags</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike span, h4 is a block level element so text-overflow need to be applied to it to work. Same for overflow:.

> This property specifies rendering when **inline content overflows** its end line box edge in the inline progression direction of **its block container element** ("the block") that **has overflow other than visible.** <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#text-overflow)</sup>

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
h4 {
    text-overflow: inherit;
    overflow: inherit;
    /* no need to inherit white-space because it inherited by default */
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h4>Ellipsis does not work with header tags</h4>
   <span>Ellipsis does work with span tags</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
h4 {
    display: inline;
}
```

and you'll see it works as expected

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

h4 {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h4>Ellipsis does not work with header tags</h4> <br>
   <span>Ellipsis does work with span tags</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `text-overflow: ellipsis` only applies to direct descendant text-nodes. You should therefore also apply the same style to the `h4` selector as well, to achieve the same effect.

I would not recommend setting `h4` to `display: inline`, because that means that you will have to manually insert breaking space after it.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

h4 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Ellipsis does not work with header tags</h4>
  <span>Ellipsis does work with span tags</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

h4 is a block element, so assign text-overflow on that element like this not in div.

```css
h4, span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
div {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h4>Ellipsis does not work with header tags</h4>
   <span>Ellipsis does work with span tags</span>
</div>
```